# Regex for ampersand, alphabetic characters and equal sign in python

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a Regex which will enable me to find something like `&dog=` or `&entropy=` in a string, I tried something like

```
&+s*^[a-zA-Z]+s*=
```

believing that I could separate the things I want with the `s*` but that didn't work out so well, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is this a URL you are trying to parse?

Comment: Yeah but I can't use a Python specific library, this has to be done via Regex like I described above. Also I am not given entire urls , only parts of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a regex you can use something like this:

```
&\w+=
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/uJ2hW4/1)**

Code

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'&\w+=')
test_str = u"asdfasdf&asdf=asdfffff&abc123=asdf\n\n\n"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

If you want to capture the value you can use capturing groups like this:

```
&(\w+)=
```

Comment: Cool this is just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Im gonna go out on a ledge and assume

```
from urllib import urlparse
urlparse.parse_qs(my_query_string)
#or 
urlparse.urlparse(my_url_string)[3]
```

is what you really want

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I have to do it with a regex because some of the strings I am given are only parts of urls and this can't be a Python specific library for constraints of the project. But thanks.